# How to map sql result to class what have constructor with parameters (interface)?

Tags: c#, sql, interface, entity-framework-6, mapping

can anyone say how can I map sql query result to class, if class have constructor with parameters, and that parameters is interface with other classes as keys. (I am trying rewrite EF6 code onto raw sql).

This is class to what i need map sql query result.

```cs
public class DiagSoftDownload
{
    public DiagSoftDownload(IGrouping<DiagSoft, LogDownload> data)
    {
        Name = data.Key.DiagSoftMark.Name;
        Version = data.Key.Version;
        Count = data.Count();
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Version { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

I am using SqlDataReaderMapper (also try dapper) but it show error on mapping, something like cant map to class with constructor.

Also i think to map just by manual creating target class in datareader loop and set fields. But sql query result return few joined tables and while Entity Framework 6 can transform it via GroupBy method by class as key to needed form for creating DiagSoftDownload class, i dont understand how to transform result to interface IGrouping<DiagSoft, LogDownload> manualy.

Here is sql query what i get from EF6 and run to get result.

```sql
SELECT [m].[LogDownloadId], [m].[Date], [m].[DiagSoftId], [m].[MemberShipId], [m.DiagSoft].[DiagSoftId], [m.DiagSoft].[CountNumbersMajor], [m.DiagSoft].[CountNumbersMinor], [m.DiagSoft].[CountNumbersPatch], [m.DiagSoft].[DiagSoftMarkId], [m.DiagSoft].[FileNameGuid], [m.DiagSoft].[VersionMajor], [m.DiagSoft].[VersionMinor], [m.DiagSoft].[VersionPatch], [m.DiagSoft.DiagSoftMark].[DiagSoftMarkId], [m.DiagSoft.DiagSoftMark].[HeavyDuty], [m.DiagSoft.DiagSoftMark].[LanId], [m.DiagSoft.DiagSoftMark].[Name], [m.DiagSoft.DiagSoftMark].[OIN], [m.DiagSoft.DiagSoftMark].[SoftApplicableArea], [m.DiagSoft.DiagSoftMark].[SoftPackageID], [m.DiagSoft.DiagSoftMark].[SoftType]
FROM [LogDownloads] AS [m]
INNER JOIN [DiagSofts] AS [m.DiagSoft] ON [m].[DiagSoftId] = [m.DiagSoft].[DiagSoftId]
INNER JOIN [DiagSoftMarks] AS [m.DiagSoft.DiagSoftMark] ON [m.DiagSoft].[DiagSoftMarkId] = [m.DiagSoft.DiagSoftMark].[DiagSoftMarkId]
WHERE [m].[MemberShipId] = 447
ORDER BY[m.DiagSoft].[DiagSoftId]
```

Here is EF6 code what i trying to rewrite to raw sql and what working.

```cs
IQueryable<DiagSoftDownload> query =
    GetDbContext.LogDownloads.Include(m => m.DiagSoft.DiagSoftMark)
    .Where(m => m.MemberShipId == VM.SelectedMembershipLog.MembershipId)
    .GroupBy(m => m.DiagSoft)
.Select(m => new DiagSoftDownload(m));               

IOrderedQueryable<DiagSoftDownload> ordered_query = query.AsQueryable()
    .OrderByDescending(m => m.Count).ThenBy(m => m.Name).ThenBy(m => m.Version);
```

I would be glad to any advice.

Comment: No way. EF6 requires parameterless constructors.

Comment: Don't do that. EF cannot look into body of your constructor and understand which fields are needed, especially when Grouping. Make projection via `Select` with constructor without parameters.